# Testing TypeORM repo find function with where option

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to test a catch error if a result is not found, using TypeORM `find` function against an entity, with an additional option of `where`

I have tried to mock the function however I cannot seem to mock the `where` bit of the function.

service file

```
try {
    historicalTypes = await this.historicalMappingDataTypesRepo.find({
     where: {
          HistoricalTypes: 'Contracts',
        },
    });
}
catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof Error) {
    this.logger.error(`Historical mapping type contracts could not found: ${e.message}`, e.stack);
  } else {
    this.logger.error(`Historical mapping type contracts could not found: ${e}`);
  }
  return;
}
```

test

```
const mockHistoricalTypes: HistoricalTypes[] = [
    {
      HistoricalTypeID: 1,
      HistoricalType: 'Contracts',
    },
];

const mockHistoricalMappingTypesRepo = {
    find: ({where}) => Promise.resolve(mockHistoricalMappingTypes),
};

beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        HistoricalMappingSchedulerService,
        {
          provide: HistoricalMappingSchedulerRepository,
          useValue: mockHistoricalMappingSchedulerRepository,
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(HistoricalMappingTypes),
          useValue: mockHistoricalMappingTypesRepo,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();
    service = module.get<HistoricalMappingSchedulerService>(HistoricalMappingSchedulerService);
});

it('should throw an error when historical type id is not found', async () => {
    await mockHistoricalMappingTypesRepo.find({
      where: {
        HistoricalMappingType: 'Testing',
      },
    });
    const mockFn = () => service.ContractHistoricalMapping();
    expect(mockFn).toThrowError();
});
```

Comment: Still having problems? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `jest.fn()` to mock the repository:

```
mockHistoricalMappingTypesRepo = new (jest.fn(() => ({
  find: jest.fn(),
})))();
```

In your test you can then control what the repository returns with `mockImplementation`:

```
mockHistoricalMappingTypesRepo.find.mockImplementation(() => throw new Error());
try {
  await service.ContractHistoricalMapping()
  fail('Should have thrown error!');
} catch (e) {
  expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(Error);
}
```